# Ehcache lookup strategy : finesse key vs query

Tags: caching, ehcache

Started using ehcache. And as with newer versions we can do a search on the value attributes, so for a given cache we can search and get a result.

For example lets say my site is caching all the users details from the start up of my application server and for new user registration I have a write behind caching engaged. Now when the the user logs in I look up the cache and get few details.

Here is what I did, key: "userId"  value : new User("name",age);

Now when required I want to find all the users whose age is above 30, then I could use a search query to retrieve the dataset. This turns out to be slower like in 1 million data, for 5 million hits it is almost 2 to 3 second.

My other idea : have the key with the age as a string for example 
key:"userId#age" with the value : new User("name",age)

Now instead of queries , use a lookup with keypattern for the key : like (anyuser#[(nextchar starts with 3 )upto 2 characters) , and return the result.

Am wondering three things.

1. Can the second idea can be implemented using ehcache? If so will this be performer?
2. I am doing anything wrong in the query searching? Taking 2 second is certainly something that do not agree with what ehcache promises.
3. What is the general strategy in naming the key? Should it be random (I do not know when this can be useful), should it contain a value concatenated in a way that it can be searched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replies to your questions, using the same numbering:

1. No, Ehcache has no methods that allows recovery of mappings using a key pattern, outside of using the search feature.
2. You are probably doing nothing wrong with your search query. The OpenSource Ehcache search is a brute force solution that does not rely on index creation. So it is slow when you have a lot of entries.
3. Key naming is up to you - especially given the answer to 1.

What you could do for your use case is maintain cache entries that are the answers to your queries. Like key `usersAbove30` with as value a list of all users matching the condition expressed in the key.

Comment: point 1. seems to be wrong, at least for newer versions, keys and be searched like other attributes, see: http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/apis/search.html#creating-a-query

Comment: You are right, my answer was outside the context of search - updating to clarify that.